# Making UWP ComboBox exceeding parent windows

Tags: c++, visual-studio, combobox, uwp

My app needs to be small in nature so I make it 500 x 100 px in size.
The problem is the ComboBox selection items are also squeezed into that small window size. Of course, I can scroll it, but it doesn't feel right this way.

Here is the picture:

[image]

Is it possible to expand the ComboBox selection list so that it exceeds the parent window? Preferably in XAML if possible

Comment: I think you means that you want the ComboBox 's hight is same as the button and the ComboBox can show the text that not be clip.

Comment: I am sorry for not being clear about this. I want the combobox items (for example there are three items 480, 720, 1080) to be shown in a layout that can exceed the parent window. In this case I want all three items can be shown all at the same time instead of 1 items with scrollbar due to small parent window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to expand the ComboBox selection list so that it exceeds the parent window?

No, this is impossible in UWP apps. While using [ComboBox](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.combobox.aspx) class, it displays the drop-down list in **PopupRoot**, which is a layer has the same view port as its parent window. Anything outside this view port will be clipped, users can't see them. For example, following is a normal ComboBox:
[image]
After I give a `Margin="-20,-30,0,0"` to the drop-down list, it looks like
[image]
The part outside the window is clipped.

Besides, The implementation of `ComboBox` will also make sure the ComboBox's selection list won't exceeds the parent window. The selection list's max height is calculated at runtime, it will be always less than the parent window's height and we can't change its value manually, so it is not possible to expand the ComboBox's selection list.

Comment: Make sense since the dimension is calculated on the fly

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible, but you can extend your page to the title bar to have at least some additional space using [CoreApplicationViewTitleBar.ExtendViewIntoTitleBar property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.core.coreapplicationviewtitlebar.extendviewintotitlebar?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=cpp#code-snippet-1).

Take a look [here](https://www.eternalcoding.com/?p=1952) and [here](http://dailydotnettips.com/2015/10/20/how-to-place-custom-xaml-content-in-the-windows-universal-apps-title-bar/). (I know the examples are written in C# but it should be similar in C++)